# How to apply saddle-point estimates of large powers on the OGF of plane rooted trees?

Tags: combinatorics, trees, analytic-combinatorics

> Let $P(z)$ the ordinary generating function of plane rooted trees and let $F(z) = e^{P(z)}$. Use saddle-point estimates of large powers to determine asymptotic estimates for $[z^n]P(z)$ and $[z^n]F(z)$.
>
> Hint: Use Lagrange inversion first to state $[z^n]P(z)$ and $[z^n]F(z)$ in a form that allows to use saddle-point estimates of large powers.
>
> Remark: You can find the section about "saddle-point estimates of large powers" from the Flajolet & Sedgewick book (p.586,587,588) below.

I do not understand how to do this.

First off, here is the theorem of Lagrange Inversion that I know from the Flajolet & Sedgewick book (p. 732):

[image]

I also know that  for $P(z)$ holds the equation

$$P(z) = z \frac{1}{1-P(z)},$$

so we can use the Lagrange Inversion on $P(z)$ by setting $y(z) = P(z)$ and $\phi(u) = \frac{1}{1-u}$. But I do not understand what this has to do with the saddle-point estimates of large powers. Could you please give me a hint?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $P(z)=z/(1-P(z))$, by $(12)$ and $(14)$ in the Lagrange Inversion Theorem, we have
$$
[z^n ]P(z) = \frac{1}{n}[u^{n - 1} ]\frac{1}{{(1 - u)^n }}
$$
and
$$
[z^n ]F(z) = [z^n ]{\rm e}^{P(z)}  = \frac{1}{n}[u^{n - 1} ]\frac{{{\rm e}^u }}{{(1 - u)^n }},
$$
respectively. We apply the "saddle-point estimate of large powers" with $A(z) = B(z) = 1/(1 - z)$, $n-1$ in place of $n$, and $\lambda=1$. We find $\zeta=1/2$ and $\xi=8$. Thus,
$$
[z^n ]P(z) = \frac{1}{n}[u^{n - 1} ]\frac{1}{{1 - u}}\frac{1}{{(1 - u)^{n - 1} }} \sim \frac{1}{n}2\frac{{2^{n - 1} }}{{(1/2)^n \sqrt {2\pi (n - 1) \cdot 8} }} \sim \frac{{4^{n - 1} }}{{\sqrt \pi  n^{3/2} }}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. Similarly, we apply the theorem with $A(z) =\mathrm{e}^z/(1 - z)$, $B(z) = 1/(1 - z)$, $n-1$ in place of $n$, and $\lambda=1$. We find $\zeta=1/2$ and $\xi=8$. Therefore,
$$
[z^n ]F(z) = \frac{1}{n}[u^{n - 1} ]\frac{{{\rm e}^u }}{{1 - u}}\frac{1}{{(1 - u)^{n - 1} }} \sim \frac{1}{n}2{\rm e}^{1/2} \frac{{2^{n - 1} }}{{(1/2)^n \sqrt {2\pi (n - 1) \cdot 8} }} \sim \sqrt {\frac{{\rm e}}{\pi }} \frac{{4^{n - 1} }}{{n^{3/2} }}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. I leave you as an exercise to check that the conditions of the "saddle-point estimate of large powers" are met.